# How to fix this for loop problem in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, linear-regression

Dataset:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sales.xlsx')
x = df['Temperature (°C)']
y = df['Ice Cream Sales ($)']
df
```

[image]

I made another table for regression squared error and used for loop to perform the y - ŷᵢ formula using this code:

```
sse = pd.DataFrame()
sse['Temperature (x)'] = x
sse['Ice Cream Sales (y)'] = y
sse['Predicted Ice Cream Sales (ŷᵢ)'] = [i for i in re]
sse['Error (y - ŷᵢ)'] = [i - round(re, 4) for i in y]
sse
```

And the output looks like this:
[image]

Desired output should look like this:

[image]

**The problem is when using the for loop, it reads every value of y as supposed to just the corresponding value in each row or index.**

Btw here's how I did the re(regression equation) as the problem might be here as to why the for loop included every y value

```
re = [round(round(slope, 4) * i + round(itc, 4), 4) for i in x]
re = pd.Series(re)
re
```

[image]

My regression equation for this dataset is:

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you don't do any roundings unless you have to... and even then you should only be rounding as a last step.

Comment: I was recreating a table and it kind of messes up the next numbers if I don't round each one of them. But yeah I definitely will next time, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vectorization, and avoid creating unnecessary intermediate objects (like `[i for i in re]`).

```
sse = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Temperature (x)': x,
        'Ice Cream Sales (y)': y,
        'Predicted Ice Cream Sales (ŷᵢ)': re,
        'Error (y - ŷᵢ)': y - re.round(4),
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this:

```
sse['Predicted Ice Cream Sales (ŷᵢ)'] = pd.Series([round(round(slope, 4) * i + round(itc, 4), 4) for i in x])
sse['Error (y - ŷᵢ)'] = y - round(sse['Predicted Ice Cream Sales (ŷᵢ)'], 4)
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I haven't yet before now, and it worked! I only changed the Error table and kept the same code in  the predicted table, it shows the same result as yours. Thanks!